# Prove using the axioms that the square of any number is nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers, axioms

How do you prove $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}, x^2 \ge 0$ using the axioms?

> [image: Here are the axioms]

My lecturer hinted you should split the cases up into $x=0$ and $x \ne 0$.

The $x=0$ case seems pretty obvious: $x^2 =x \cdot x = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$ (however I can't think of any axioms to justify this??)

I don't know how to approach the $x \ne 0$ case.

Comment: The remaining cases are $x>0$ and $x<0$ by O1. In the case $x>0$ , you can use O4

Comment: In the case $x<0$ use $$x<0\implies 0<-x$$ by O3 and again apply O4

Answer (score 2):

According to trichotomy $O_1$, you have either $x >0$ or $x<0$.

If $x >0$, then according to $O_4$ you get $x^2>0$ as desired.

And if $x <0$ then using $O_3$ you get $x + (-x) < -x$, i.e. $0 < -x$.

Using what is above $ 0 < (-x) \cdot (-x)$.

With $F_9$

$$0 = (-x)0 = (-x)(-x + x)= (-x)(-x) + (-x)x = (-x)(-x) + (-1)x^2 = (-x)(-x) + -x^2$$

Adding $x^2$ on both sides of the equality your get $x^2 = (-x)(-x)$ by use of $F_4$.

Plugging that in the inequality $ 0 < (-x) \cdot (-x)$ you conclude again that $0 < x^2$.